# Equality of laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform

Assuming that Laplace Transforms of two functions  $f$ and $g$ are equal, is it true that $f=g$?
There is one-to-one correspondence between functions and their Laplace Transforms, so it seems to me that it is true.

Comment: Yes, the transform is unique in the sense that if $\mathcal{L}(f) = \mathcal{L}(g)$ then $\int_0^t f(x)-g(x)dx = 0$ for all $t$. The integral condition is the best you can do as any two functions that disagrees only on a countable set of points will have the same transform since integrals does not care about single points (only intervals contribute to the value of the integral). Another way to say this is that the two functions are equal [almost everywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a theorem knows as [Lerchs theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchsTheorem.html). I will give a standard proof of this below. I will restrict myself to continuous functions, but the generalization to integrable functions (continuous almost everywhere) is straight forward (replace equal with equal [almost everywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere)).

We first start with a lemma:

> Lemma 1: If $g$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$ and $\int_0^1 g(x) x^n dx = 0$ for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$ then $g(x) \equiv 0$ for $x\in[0,1]$.

Proof: Fix $\epsilon > 0$. By the [Weierstrass approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Weierstrass_approximation_theorem) we can find a polynomial $P(\epsilon,x)$ s.t. $|P(\epsilon,x) - g(x)|_\infty < \epsilon$. The hypothesis on $g$ implies $\int_0^1 g(x)P(\epsilon,x)dx = 0$. Taking $\epsilon \to 0$ we get $\int_0^1 g^2(x) dx = 0$ which implies $g(x) \equiv 0$.

We can now prove a second lemma:

> Lemma 2: If $g$ is a continuous function and if $\mathcal{L}(g)(s) = 0$ for all $s \geq a$ then $g(x) \equiv 0$.

Proof: Fix $s_* \geq a$. At $s=s_* + n + 1$ the condition $\mathcal{L}(g)(s) = 0$ implies that

$$0 = \mathcal{L}(g)(s) = \int_0^\infty g(x) e^{-xs} dx = \int_0^1 x^{n} \left(x^{s_*}g(-\log(x))\right)dx$$

for all $n=0,1,2,\ldots$ where we have made the substitution $e^{-x}\to x$ in the last equality. By the above lemma it follows that $x^{s_*}g(-\log(x)) \equiv 0$ which implies $g(x) \equiv 0$.

We are now ready to prove the theorem:

> Lerch theorem: If $g,f$ are continuous functions and if $\mathcal{L}(f) = \mathcal{L}(g)$ for all $s\geq s_*$ then $g\equiv f$.

By the linearity of the Laplace transform we have

$$0 = \mathcal{L}(f) - \mathcal{L}(g) = \int_0^\infty (f(x)-g(x)) e^{-sx}dx$$

for all $s\geq s_*$. By the second lemma above it follows that $f(x)-g(x) \equiv 0$.

Comment: Your application of lemma $1$ in lemma $2$ requires that $x^{s_{*}} g(-\log(x))$ is continuous as a function of $x$ on $[0,1]$. It's not clear to me why this need by the case, since $-\log(x)$ blows up as $x \to 0$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 You are on to an important point that I did not comment on. This is exactly why we have that mysterious $s_*$ in there. We need the powers of $x^{s_*}$ to ensure that it doesn't blow up (the limit of $x^{s_*}g(x)$ as $x\to 0$ is the limit of $g(x)e^{-s_*x}$ as $x\to \infty$ which is zero). For this we also have to assume that $g$ doesn't grow too fast, i.e. that $g(x) < Me^{ax}$.

Comment: I see. So does the result not generally hold if $g(x) >> Me^{ax}$? Or is the proof just harder?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 We always need some control over the growth of the function in order to be able to Fourier/Laplace transform it in the first place. Typically such functions do not have a Fourier/Laplace transform so they are not that relevant.

Comment: Of course, right. Thanks.

Comment: thx. great explanation, very useful result.

Comment: @CuteBrownie I don't understand. Where do I claim that should be the case?

Answer (score 2):

This is almost exactly the same idea as the above answer, but I keep it as another formulation of the same idea.

Here is the precise formulation and proof of the theorem:

> Lerch's theorem (Uniqueness of inverse of Laplacian): Let $f $ be a function defined on all nonnegative real numbers and is continuous except on a finite number of points. Suppose there exist constants $M, a$ such that $|f (x)| \leq Me^{ax} $ for all $x $. If $L[f](s)$ is zero for all $s > s_0$ for some constant $s_0$, then $f$ is identically zero except on the points of discontinuity.

Proof:

First assume that $f$ has no discontinuities. We'll prove the general case for a function having finite number of discontinuities at the end.

For any polynomial $P (x)= \sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k $ we have that $\int_0^\infty e^{-st}P (e^{-t})f (t)dt=...=\sum a_kL[f](s+k) \equiv 0 $ for $s > s_0$. I skipped the easy calculation and the reader can check the "..." part. Letting $x = e^{-t} $ this condition the last integral becomes $$\int_0^1 x^{s-1}P (x)f (-\log x)dx \equiv 0,$$ for all $s>s_0$. Now fix $s_1 > \max\{s_0, 1, a+1\}$. Then $$x^{s_1-1}|f (-\log x)| \leq Me^{s_1-a-1} $$ so that the function $$G:=x^{s_1-1}f (-\log x), 0 < x \leq 1, $$ approaches zero as $x $ approaches $0$ from the right. Define $G(0)$ to be zero. Then $G$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$. Also remember that the value of an integral does not change if we define or redefine a function at a point. $G $ is thus a function that is bounded and continuous on $[0,1] $ and satisfies $\int_0^1 G (x)P (x)dx  \equiv 0$ for any polynomial $P $. If we now approximate $G$ by polynomials that converge uniformly to $G$ and use the argument of Lemma 1 given by user @Winther above we have that $G \equiv 0$ and thus $f \equiv 0$.

We get a similar result if we assume that $f $ has only a finite number of discontinuities, and the result would be that $f $ is identically equal to zero except possibly on its finite number of discontinuous points. In the course of proving that we would need to break $f $, and  thus $G$, into a finite number of continuous parts, use several subintervals $[x_m, x_{m+1}] $, and use different approximating Weierstrass polynomials for each of these subintervals to get that $G $, and thus $f$, is equivalent to zero except on discontinuous points.

The majority of the proof and the precise statement of this theorem is almost directly copied from the following books's Appendix II, page 678:

D. L. Kreider, R. G. Kuller, D. R. Ostberg, F. W. Perkins, An Introduction to Linear Analysis, Addison-Wesley Publishing Co., Inc., Reading, Mass.-Don Mills, Ont. 1966.

Notice that the argument doesn't work if we do not assume $f $ to be of exponential order (i.e. having the constants $M, a $ as above). However, as a practical matter, I remember an MIT professor said that almost all continuous functions we shall encounter in real life problems will be of exponential order.

Comment: "Winther's answer is flawed because it is not necessarily true that" Sorry, this make no sense to me. Where in my answer do I claim that we should have $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x) e^{(-s+n+1)x} = 0$? I don't know what you are talking about here.

Comment: I think the issue is it looks liek you are calling out them? It would have been better if you commented the error and wrote the correct answer here itself.

Comment: No, my issue is not that it's being "called out" - right should be right. The issue is that it did not make any sense. Now it's a bit clearer what is meant, but its still wrong. $s_*$ is a fixed number - it does not depend on $n$. We start with the assumption that $L(g)(s)$ is zero for all sufficiently large $s > s_*$. In particular, its zero for all the numbers $s = s_* + n + 1$. This again translates into $\int_0^1 x^n h(x) dx = 0$ where $h(x) = x^{s_*} g(-\log(x))$. And we apply Weierstrass to this function. The key thing is that the number $s_*$ is fixed from the beginning.

Comment: I don't need for $s$ to be any number in this lemma as you seem to insist here. We only need the fact that $L(g)(s)$ is zero for all sufficiently large $s$. And I pick a set of these numbers $s = s_* + n + 1$ for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$. Rewriting $s_*$ in terms of $s$ and $n$ and then claiming that my $h$ depends on $n$ is therefore not true.

Comment: Oh ok @Winter thank you you are right. So you first fixed s* and *then* defined $s_n $.

Comment: Thanks for providing a reference.